# Stop mouseDown event when mouseDoubleClick occured

Tags: java, swt

I have a control which is listened for both mouseDown and mouseDoubleClick events. However when mouseDoubleClick occure, I don't need mouseDown event to be handled. (Now both events fired when doubleClick happens)
How can I stop handling mouseDown event when mouseDoubleClick occured?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you can do something like:

```
private boolean doubleClicked = false;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
{
     if (evt.getClickCount() == 2)
     {
         doubleClicked = true;
         // Handle here your double click
     }
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
{
     if (doubleClicked)
     {
         return;
     }
     // Handle here your mouse down
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt)
{
     doubleClicked = false;
}
```

So I don't know if this is relevant with SWT or not, but this is with AWT MouseListener.

---

I searched a bit, so I think this can work for SWT:

```
// Place this in your class body, otherwise you have to make it final
// and that is not what we want.
private boolean doubleClicked = false;

// Mouse Double Click
public void handleEvent(Event evt)
{
     doubleClicked = true;
     // Handle here your double click
}

// Mouse Down
public void handleEvent(Event evt)
{
     if (doubleClicked)
     {
         return;
     }
     // Handle here your mouse down
}

// Mouse Up
public void handleEvent(Event evt)
{
     doubleClicked = false;
}
```